# Overwritten file not updated on Android

Tags: android

I am writing several files to a directory on the SD card, creating some and overwriting others. My tablet is connected to my Windows laptop, where I am looking at this directory and opening those files. In my Android app, after closing each file, I make sure to call `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`. This ensures that all the new files show up immediately, but somehow the overwritten files still seem to retain their original content--this is, until I unplug the USB cable and plug it back in.

This is on an Acer Iconia A500 running ICS.

Why isn't it working, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have the A500 as well, running ICS, it doesn't seem to update completely until you restart the tablet.